# How to print all options in drop-down menu in Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a employee scorecard in Excel, basically it looks like that:
[image]

So Cell B2 is a drop-down list(data validation cell) that read employees' name from another tab(Tab 2, columns A1:A1000), so after people pick different name, those core metrics will refresh(the data generate those metrics is already linked to the data source).

[image]

Supervisor will print this scorecard and talk to their employees.

However there are more than hundreds of employees, so I wonder is there any easy way via VBA that can print all the options in the drop-down lists for every employees.I did some searches in Google, and cannot find anything works for me.

Much appreciated

Comment: Is B2 a data validation cell or did you use a drop down box?

Comment: it is a data validation cell, sorry for confusion

Comment: Do you want to print each employee on a separate page?

Comment: Yes, normally. I pick one name from the list then wait the data is refreshing, then i will print this page. then i go next employee, i think it is a loop, but i spend some time, cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to iterate through the data validation cell. Change the worksheet name and cell reference as needed.
You will have to add the print code inside the for/each/next loop

```
Sub Iterate_Through_data_Validation()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range


'Which cell has data validation
   Set dvCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
'Determine where validation comes from
   Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value
    'add some print page code here
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through the combobox list:

I threw this together for you.  I didn't have time to test but it should work.  You need to replace "ComboBox1" with whatever your control name is.  You also need to change `el.Name = "EmployeeList"` to the correct sheet name.

```
Sub printEmployees()
    On Error GoTo catch
    Err.Clear
    GoTo try

try:
    Dim el, sc As Worksheet


    Set sc = ActiveSheet
    Set el = Sheets.Add
    el.Name = "EmployeeList"

    sc.Activate

    i = 0
    For Each lItem In Me.ComboBox1.List
        el.Cells(1, i) = Me.ComboBox1.List(i)
    i = i + 1
    Next

    el.PrintOut

finally:
    On Error Resume Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    el.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set sc = Nothing
    Set el = Nothing
    Exit Sub

catch:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume finally

End Sub
```